# Intercept link LinkMovementMethod with a Yes/No dialog

Tags: android, linkmovementmethod

I have a standard [`LinkMovementMethod`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/LinkMovementMethod) established in my `TextView` to push a web Activity of some sort when the user touches a link. However, I want to establish a "do you want to see the link" dialog rather than taking the user straight to the webpage. I've tried overriding the touch methods but it all gets a little convoluted. A little help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish it in two ways:

- **Create custom Spans**: more complicated, but you can accomplish more customised text consisting of clickable parts (or bold, differently coloured etc). To know more, check out [ClickableSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan) and [SpannableStringBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder)
- **Extend `LinkMovementMethod`** to accept custom click listener

In my opinion second solution is better in basic cases like yours. Here is how you can do it:

1. Copy this java class: [InternalLinkMovementMethod](https://gitlab.com/Commit451/LabCoat/commit/0da57c371815902f4ba24fcd7bceaa1e7a8d7bb7#1869e1cd937878326e16d1ab7139f68380c48172) to your project
2. Add set the link movement method of your TextView to this custom one, providing a click listener:

```java
OnLinkClickedListener clickListener = new OnLinkClickedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLinkClicked(String linkText) {
        // here you can handle your click, eg show the dialog
        // `linkText` is the text being clicked (the link)
        // return true if handled, false otherwise
    }
}

yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new InternalLinkMovementMethod(clickListener));
```

Comment: Your `linkText` is the URL?

Comment: Yes, its the text being clicked. Updated my answer

Comment: I don't remember what I was after here but the project is long since completed. I'll accept and move on.