# Android. How to get substring from Spannable which was clicked?

Tags: android, html, android-webview, android-view, android-spannable

I have html string:

```
htmlString = "This is a <a href=\"https://translate.google.com/\">link</a> and another link <a href=\"https://google.com/\">link2</a>"
```

I set this String to my TextView. Here is my code:

```
tvText.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
```

And also I set `LinkMovementMethod`, links to be clickable.

```
tvText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Everything is fine, but links open in the browser by default, and I need to open them inside the application in web view.

Can I somehow get the link from the clicked String ? So that I can load the link in web view.

Or do I need to manually search for all links in the String and put clicks on them (ClickableSpan)?
Please, help me.

Comment: I guess this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338333/intercept-link-linkmovementmethod-with-a-yes-no-dialog

Comment: I guess this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338333/intercept-link-linkmovementmethod-with-a-yes-no-dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

Extend LinkMovementMethod to accept custom click listener

Copy this java class: InternalLinkMovementMethod to your project
Add set the link movement method of your TextView to this custom one, providing a click listener:

```
OnLinkClickedListener clickListener = new OnLinkClickedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLinkClicked(String linkText) {
        // here you can handle your click, eg show the dialog
        // `linkText` is the text being clicked (the link)
        // return true if handled, false otherwise
    }
}

yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new InternalLinkMovementMethod(clickListener)
```

Base on: [Intercept link LinkMovementMethod with a Yes/No dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338333/intercept-link-linkmovementmethod-with-a-yes-no-dialog)