# Catch exactly which string was clicked in this textview witch was made by SpannableStringBuilder?

Tags: android, textview, try-catch, spannablestringbuilder

I have textview with SpannableStringBuilder.

```
SpannableStringBuilder span = getSpanFromStringArray();
span.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bitmap), span.length() - text.length(), span.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textview.setText(span);
```

Haw can I catch exactly which string was clicked in this textview?

if I'm using

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
for (Text line : textArray) {
   builder.append(line);
   ClickableSpan click = new ClickableSpan() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View widget) {
          Toast.makeText(getContext(),"line",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       };
   };
   builder.setSpan(click, 0, line.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
```

but always takes first line in array.

Comment: explain better you problem, please.

Comment: I have textview. Textview contains SpannableString. If user click on item (string) from this textview, I need to know which item was clicked.

Comment: try with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74127359/android-how-to-get-substring-from-spannable-which-was-clicked